# How to run Oracle in SQLFiddle

Tags: oracle, sqlfiddle

I am new to Oracle sql.  I got a piece of code from the web, and paste it into sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/):

For the schema, I created a temp table, which will be used in the sql query:

```
CREATE Global Temporary TABLE temp
 (id number
 ,x number)
 ,y CHAR(50))
 ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

I clicked build schema, which tells me "Schema Ready".

Then I paste the following query which is from Oracle official website on the right pane:

```
-- available online in file 'sample1'
DECLARE
   x NUMBER := 100;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      IF MOD(i,2) = 0 THEN     -- i is even
         INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is even');
      ELSE
         INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is odd');
      END IF;
      x := x + 100;
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

When I press run sql, and it returns errors:

> ORA-06550: line 3, column 18: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < / >
>   at in is mod remainder not rem  <> or != or ~= >= <=
>   <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || multiset member
>   submultiset

Answer (score 4):

You need to change default query terminator(<kbd>[;]</kbd>) to sth else than `;` and you may need to add this separator and new line between blocks of code:

[image]

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1fbcb/2/0)**</kbd>

```
DECLARE
   x NUMBER := 100;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      IF MOD(i,2) = 0 THEN     
         INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is even');
      ELSE
         INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i, x, 'i is odd');
      END IF;
      x := x + 100;
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

> **[What's up with that [ ; ] button under each panel?](http://sqlfiddle.com/about.html)**
>
> This obscure little button determines how the queries in each of the panels get broken up before they are sent off to the database.
> This button pops open a dropdown that lists different "query
> terminators." Query terminators are used as a flag to indicate (when
> present at the end of a line) that the current statement has ended.
> The terminator does not get sent to the database; instead, it merely
> idicates how I should parse the text before I execute the query.
>
> Oftentimes, you won't need to touch this button; the main value this feature will have is in
> defining stored procedures. This is because it is often the case that
> within a stored procedure's body definition, you might want to end a
> line with a semicolon (this is often the case). Since my default query
> terminator is also a semicolon, there is no obvious way for me to see
> that your stored procedure's semicolon isn't actually the end of the
> query. Left with the semicolon terminator, I would break up your
> procedure definition into incorrect parts, and errors would certainly
> result. Changing the query terminator to something other than a
> semicolon avoids this problem.

Comment: Could you describe what you're changing it from and to? And how to change it? Just clicking that link doesn't tell me what I need to change...

Comment: Thank you very much lad2025.  It really helps me because you know at the beginning level of a programming everything wrong will make the thing mess up and no clue to solve it.

Comment: I changed the query terminator which is the last icon to /, and add / at the end of my query, then the query works. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1816353 I gently remind that answer is still not accepted

Comment: I'm going to copy the fiddle into the question in case it ever disappears.